# Do we need a higher rate of new questions right now?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that the visit stats have tailed off quite dramatically over the last week or so: upwards of 400 down to 200 or so.

The number of new questions also seems to have diminished, so maybe now is a good time for us all to start asking new ones with the kind of enthusiasm that [kenorb](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/kenorb) brought to the party when the site launched?

For my part, I'm travelling today and tomorrow, but will attempt to come up with something meaningful thereafter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More questions certainly would be great, but a low-activity period (the length of which varies from site to site) after the public beta start is normal. For more information, see [What is the typical growth pattern of a new beta site in the first few weeks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227007/295684)

If I perceive correctly, we did get something of an extra boost from "can a paradox kill an AI?" being in Hot Network Questions for a few days. It would be great if we could produce more content that's both high-quality and interesting to a lot of people.

So yes, if anyone has additional well-thought-out questions in mind, we would be happy to have them!

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely been a fall-off, but as others have said, it will take time for people to find the site and become engaged.  I feel like one of the most important thing to do in the meantime is keep asking *some* quality questions, and/or get additional answers to existing questions, such that first time visitors won't perceive the site as dormant.  From a network science POV, we want a "preferential attachment" sort of scenario, where new nodes attach themselves to this node and grow our network.